# Are dividends on YahooFinance adjusted for splits?

Tags: dividends, yahoo-finance, stock-split, backtesting

Here is an [example](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOLD/history?period1=978044400&period2=1514502000&interval=div%7Csplit&filter=div&frequency=1d) from YahooFinance of dividends paid over time.

I assume these numbers are USD - is this correct?

My other question is if these dividends are adjusted for splits? In this example this does not apply because the last split was in June 2004, but I would like to know in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are dividends on Yahoo Finance adjusted for splits?

Yes they are, I found [this handy link](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/how-does-yahoo-finance-adjust-stock-data-for-splits-and-dividends) to a previous question with a great answer.

> I assume these numbers are USD - is this correct?

It being listed on the NASDAQ is your first clue that it is in USD, it also says right under the stock name that it is in USD. So yes, it is in USD.

Hope this helps!