# Stock Split seems not to have changed the Share Price. Why?

Tags: stocks, india, financial-literacy, stock-split, bonus

I was recently looking at the financial charts of TCS(Tata Consultancy Services) and noticed that the TCS offered 1:1 bonus on 31st May, 2018.

I noticed that the price of the share stock did not change. So i went on some other sites to verify and found the same. Below are some snapshot of the that from different sites. Can some please explain if there has been a stock slit/bonus how come the price of the stock did not change.

**Snapshot from Moneycontrol:**
[image]

**Snapshot from Investing**
[image]

**Snapshot from CapitalMarket**
[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Can some please explain if there has been a stock slit/bonus how come the price of the stock did not change

Before the stock split the stock was priced around 3500. Once a stock split happens, all financial sites factor the split and adjust the price. The reason for adjustment is to give a good comparison; else it will look like there was a 50% decline in the price. It will also help to find the actual effect of the split; i.e. whether the price moved up or down.

Related [How does Yahoo finance adjust stock data for splits and dividends?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/how-does-yahoo-finance-adjust-stock-data-for-splits-and-dividends?s=1|78.4291)

Answer (score 11):

You would need to have remembered the *actual stock price* before, and compared it to the stock price now.   E.g. I remember when GOOG had spent a couple years climbing to about $780, and then blam, it was $112.  That was a 7:1 split.

**Charts correct for the split**.  If you looked at a GOOG chart a week after the 7:1 split, the chart would show *that GOOG had been in the $100 range the entire time*.  Working as intended.

As I am constantly explaining to my Board of Directors, **business data has a purpose** and the presentation should serve that purpose.  For instance our business has gate revenue.  We pay 10-20% to the booking company and credit card clearinghouse.  The Board loves puffing up our numbers by claiming $24,000 gate (and $4000 fees) when the real spendable money from gate is only $20,000, and that is the number the Board should ponder.

So the charts are distilling the info down to what most chart users need to see: the actual market performance of the company.  Showing a 2:1 lurch there would provide no useful info and only make the chart harder to read.

Comment: For those that don't like remembering things, you could probably also use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine

Comment: @Scott it would be more useful to link to the actual Wayback Machine and not to a Wikipedia article on it: https://web.archive.org/

Comment: @KevinVanDyck [why not both?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180527121738/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine)

Comment: @Jeff, sure, both works too :p